# MySQL Trigger Insert Before Not Firing

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to add a trigger for auditing to initialize a datetime field on an insert.  Does anyone see what might be causing this trigger to not fire???

```
USE example;

CREATE TABLE USERS (
    ID  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FULLNAME    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `PASSWORD`  CHAR(88) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    FLAGS   TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    CREATED DATETIME,
    UPDATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE INDEX(EMAIL),
    PRIMARY KEY( ID )
);

DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER USER_T BEFORE INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END;$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO USERS(FULLNAME, `PASSWORD`, EMAIL) VALUES('Admin', 'sQnzu7wkTrgkQZF+0G1hi5AI3Qmzvv0bXgc5THBqi7mAsdd4Xll27ASbRt9fEyavWi6m0QP9B8lThf+rDKy8hg==', 'root@localhost');
```

Comment: try `SET NEW.CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: Nope, still getting a null value for datetime :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `;` as a delimiter here

```
 SET NEW.CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER USER_T BEFORE INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That was it!  The silly semicolon before the $$ was causing the issue.  Thank you very much!  Will accept when Stackoverflow allows me too.  Cheers.

Comment: Nice, also I believe from mysql version 5.6 onwards you wont need to create a trigger to do what you want. MySQL will accept `TIMESTAMP` on more than one field